# Create site collection using jsom

Tags: javascript, site-collection, jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am wondering if creation of site collections with javascript on SharePoint hosted sites, is still not possible?

If not, is it possible to use the site collection creation form `_layouts/15/online/CreateSites.aspx`in a way that it can be made available for specific users that need to create site collections?

What other alternatives do I have to provide creation of site collections to specific non-administrator users?

Comment: You can enable self site creation [reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263483.aspx). User can apply and create their site by fill in a form.

Comment: True ... but the reason that I would like to do it by a self made script, is that the site, after creation, needs to be populated with specific lists and document libraries.